# jenkins helm installPlugins is unable to download docker, why is this?

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes-helm

My installPlugins in my helm charts looks like below, everything installs except Docker, I am able to install this plugin through the ui, even if I replace Docker with some other plugin it doesn't work. Any idea what I should check?

```js
installPlugins:
    - kubernetes:1.27.6
    - workflow-aggregator:2.6
    - git:4.4.5
    - configuration-as-code:1.46
    - Docker:1.2.1
```

Comment: Maybe mark as answered or delete your Q then?

Comment: @IanW says can't mark as answered until 2 days

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, I need to use the id and not the name of the plugin. So in this case

docker-plugin:1.2.1 not Docker:1.2.1